# Change language in Fifa '08

Tags: ps3, fifa-08

I'd like to change the language of the commentators in Fifa '08. Is there any way to do this?

The language was set when I first launched the game, but I don't know how to change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change you language in the **PS3 settings, not the in-game settings**. Unfortunately this also changes the language of *everything* in the game, but it's the only way to change the commentary.

To do this, go to the PS3 Menu > Settings > System Settings > System Language.

Comment: Thanks! Will that also change the language of every other game, in addition to Fifa and the system? Is there no way to get back the first-run language picker?

Comment: Sadly, this is the only way to change the commentator language. And yeah, it will change the language settings of your other games too.

Comment: @Keaanu Coming quite late on this... Will this also change the trophies, meaning that I will get two sets of trophies for the same game (which would be a mess) or a single set but just with the name/descriptions translated? I'm afraid to try and fall in the first option... Didn't want to ask new question for this, you can update your answer with this detail. Thx! :)

Comment: @LudoMC It appears as though if you gain trophies while your PS3 is set to a different language, then the text of those trophies will _always_ be set to that language. This results in a mixed-language set of trophies (though you won't get the *same* trophies multiple times for completing them with different language settings).